# Is the javascript Class "chzn-select" more than just a class name?

Tags: javascript

I found a shopping cart online that i was interested in replicating however upon looking up the class name chzn-select I have noticed that this is commonly used possibly just to mark a specific kind of content or maybe its part of more than just a naming convention?

My question is, Is Chzn-Select More than just a commonly used class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This represents a [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) select, a select box plugin for jQuery.

Chosen supports grouping, searching, multiselection and other features, making simple selects a lot more attractive and rich.